# I am getting this issue while clicking on any button in my we application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

Comment: You probably have to correct the connnection string or configure SQL server to allow remote connections, its nothing wrong with button.

Comment: Actually it's working in my local good but when i move the same code into staging server for testing that time it is showing.

Comment: Your local is different from staging, so you must check the environment, this could help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci